# VS Code ask for password repeatedly when opening different folder on same host

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I have connected to a remote `Ubuntu` host from Windows using `VS Code` and using it for remote development. Often times I open different code repositories in VS Code but every time I have to open a different folder despite having the connection established the VS Code ask for password.

It seems that once we are commented to a remote host then successive opening of different folder from same host should not prompt for password.

Is there any setting I am missing or should do to resolve this or save password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're connecting to an ssh remote.

There are two ways to authenticate an ssh connection, via password and via public/private key. When using the latter you don't need to enter the password each time.

To use the public/private keys here's what you have to do:

- You first need a pair (public/private) of ssh keys. On windows you can use `ssh-keygen` to generate them for you and put them in the default ssh config folder ( `~/.ssh/`)
- You then have to configure the remote server to allow your ssh key, you can do this in two ways:

  - with the `ssh-copy-id` command if available (I think on windows it's not there, but you can try)
  - by manually add your **public** key (`~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) to the`.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the host machine

Here's a link to know more about passwordless logins via ssh: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/passwordless-ssh

Comment: This is okay if I was using any command line tool but this is not what I am looking for as 
far as `vscode` is concerned and the use case which I shared.

Comment: vscode will use your ssh key, they even tell you to create it on their tutorial: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh-tutorial

Comment: While this is a correct answer, it's an answer to another question and not the one asked. The question was not "how to get rid of a password prompt" but "why is vs code repeatedly asking for a password, even though I'm already connected".
Edit: and it seems to be a bug in the SSH extension: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6227

Answer (score -2):

1. Open git bash on Windows
2. cd .ssh
3. ssh-copy-id -i id_ed25519.pub your-username@your-server